# static IPs and netplan

Tags: networking, dhcp, netplan, static-ip

I am trying to create static IP addresses in Ubuntu.  I have studied posts, etc. and see that this info is `/etc/network/interfaces`.  I noticed that the ethernet name, for instance is not consistent:

```
iface ens3 inet static
    address 192.168.122.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.122.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

other than the file `/etc/netplan/ens3.yaml` is created containing

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            dhcp4: no
            addresses: [192.168.122.100/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.122.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [8.8.8.8]
```

of course, all of the IP addresses would need to be changed for my system.

I also need keywords on how to do this with the wlan also.

Am I on the right track?  Any information will be appreciated.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -al /etc/netplan  
total 28  
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov  7 05:24 .  
drwxr-xr-x 142 root root 12288 Nov  7 06:05 ..  
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   683 Sep 24 19:27 50-cloud-init.yaml  
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   207 Nov  6 22:48 eth0.old_yaml  
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   293 Nov  7 04:41 wlan0.old_yaml'''
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml  
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes  
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's  
# network configuration capabilities, write a file  
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:  
# network: {config: disabled}
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/netplan$ cat eth0.yaml  
network:  
    version: 2  
    renderer: networkd  
    ethernets:  
      eth0:  
        dhcp4: no  
        addresses: [192.168.0.220/24]  
        gateway4: 192.168.0.1  
        nameservers:  
          addresses: [68.105.28.11,8.8.8.8]
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/netplan$ cat wlan0.yaml  
network:  
  version: 2  
  renderer: networkd  
  wifis:  
    wlan0:  
      dhcp4: no  
      dhcp6: no  
      addresses: [192.168.0.221/24]  
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1  
      nameservers:  
        addresses: [68.105.28.11, 8.8.8.8]  
      access-points:  
        "xxxxxxx":
        password: "xxxxxxxx"
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d$ cat 99-disable-network-config.cfg
network:
  config: disabled
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/netplan$ hostname -I
192.168.0.44 2600:8802:3500:f400:798d:ff80:901c:e944
```

Comment: Yes. `$ netplan try` is your friend. The name of the netplan file I think is irrelevant, and the docs show you how to match interfaces on mac address and more.  Feel free to answer your own question when you've figured it out.

Comment: What version Ubuntu? Is this a Desktop or Server installation? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: Netplan has very detailed and beginner friendly documentation: [NETPLAN](https://netplan.io/). It wouldn't make sense to rewrite it.

Comment: netplan documentation great.  when i create eth0.yaml                                                      network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.216/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [68.105.28.11,8.8.8.8]
netplan try                                                                                                               ERROR: cannot create file run/systemd/network/10-netplan-eth0: Failed to create file “/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-eth0.link.BS6KT0”: Permission denied

Comment: An error occurred: the configuration could not be generated

Reverting.
Something really bad happened while reverting config: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '10-netplan-wlan0.network'
You should verify the netplan YAML in /etc/netplan and probably run 'netplan apply' again.

Comment: then added /etc/network/interfacesauto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.216
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 68.105.28.11   same issue

Comment: You need to use `sudo` when applying the netplan. You should edit and format your question.

Comment: If you answer my question from 23 hours ago, I might be able to help. You don't do /etc/network/interfaces and netplan .yaml files at the same time. Also edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/netplan` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`... and please don't put that output into comments, but rather, edit it into your original question.

Comment: so sorry, heynnma,  the version is 20.10.  so you're saying that i should create the .yaml files and get rid of the stuff in interfaces, right?

Comment: @markum Correct, because 20.10 *only* will use Netplan - the `/etc/network/interfaces` item is redundant and superseded by Netplan.

Comment: When my yamls are as above in my original question there was no difference.  when adding the 99-disable-network-config.cfg there was no difference.  no difference being that there was no static address as indicated but rather one selected by DHCP.